# Append elements into different containers depending on conditions with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array, looking as simple as

```
var labels = ['label 1', 'label2', ..., 'label n']
```

Now if I want to put them as visual elements in the chart, I can do like this:

```
    var legendItem = legendArea
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(labels)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr({class: 'legend-element'});
```

`legendArea` becomes a parent for all the labels now. But, I have a more complex scenario, where I need to put labels not in `legendArea` directly but create a wrapper `g` element first inside `legendArea`, which will then contain a set of labels, depending on some criteria that I get from each label.

As a result, I will have a number of `g` elements with a set of labels inside of them, one can have 5, another can have 8, any number, as they are not spread evenly.

What I see now, is I need to run a loop through all labels array elements, check if current labels conforms to criteria, create a new wrapper element if needed and then append. But this solution seems to be not D3-style, as in most cases it's possible to do functional style code with D3, not `for..loop`.

I suspect I can do something more custom here, something like:

```
    var legendItem = legendArea
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(labels)
      .enter()
      // Do some unknown D3 magic here to create a new wrapper element and append the label to it.
      .attr({class: 'legend-element'});
```

Please advise on how to do it in D3 fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a list of categories, use that as data for the `g` elements, and then add the rest with filters:

```
var cats = svg.selectAll("g").data(categories)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(10," + ((i+1) * 30) + ")"; });

cats.selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) { return data.filter(function(e) { return e.category == d; }); })
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

This works similar to [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/), except that the nesting isn't in the data itself (although you can modify the data structures for that as well), but by referencing different data structures.

The first block of code simply adds a `g` element for each category. The second block of code does a nested selection (and is hence able to reference the data bound to the `g` element just before). In the `.data()` function, we take all the data and filter out the items that match the current category. The rest is bog-standard D3 again.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7aypmye/).

Comment: The issue is I have no clear criteria about which item is in which group and how many cats there at all from the start because I define it dynamically, depending on each item's position which is set dynamically too when the element is to be added to DOM.

Comment: You can embed this in the usual D3 update pattern to update the categories when you get more data.